# What kind of parameter does addActionListener take?

Tags: java, swing

I would like to override the `JButton` method and in the meantime be able to set events for every button I create in the constructor,

```java
public class Bouton extends JButton{
    public Bouton(String label, Label screen, Result listBoutons){
        super();
        this.setText(label);
        this.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);      
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e, Result listBoutons){
        String event = ( (Bouton) e.getSource() ).getText();
        System.out.println(listBoutons.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the API for the `addActionListener(...)` method. It will tell you the parameter.

Comment: As name suggests `addActionListener` takes `ActionListener` (or its subtype). If that doesn't answer your question then please clarify it.

Comment: As you can see iin the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener))  it takes an [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) so for `addActionListener(this)` the class need to implement `ActionListener`

Answer (score 0):

I have found it !

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Bouton extends JButton implements ActionListener
{
private Result listBoutons = new Result();

public Bouton(String label , Label screen , Result listBoutons)
{
    super();
    this.setText(label);
    this.listBoutons = listBoutons;
    this.addActionListener(this);       
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String event = ( (Bouton) e.getSource() ).getText();
    System.out.println(event);
}

}
```